# NFC Photography Identification

Tags: facebook-graph-api, nfc, photography

There was a music event a friend of mine went to and they had a few photographers waling around out there.  The photographers took photos that were instantly uploaded to the users facebook account via an NFC wristband.  The workflow when it was explained to me looks like this:

Step-1 Get a nfc wristband at the Kiosk- Facebook will be encoded into the wristband.

Step-2 Walk around the event.  If a photographer takes your picture, hold your wrist to the camera and the image will be watermarked with event/sponsor logos at the bottom and posted to your facebook account .

So, I was thinking how this could possibly be done- I googled and googled, but I got nothing.  Here's my guess- All the FB authentication can be in the wristband. An EyeFi SD card has the ability to take a photo and transmit it.  NFC Arduino reader could read the persons wristband, authenticate, then go into the images and pull the last photo that was taken and post it to the users fb page.   What do you think?

Comment: I think this "question" is too broad and it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I agree with @Okuma.Scott, however, I would too like to know how they did this...Hence a few further questions: What information did they request from you in order to encode the wristband? Did you have to give them your FB login data? Did you have to log into FB and activate their FB application for your account? Did you have to like their page/fried their FB user? Were the photos posted directly through your account or through a FB app linked to your account or through their page/their user that linked you on the photo?

Answer (score 0):

We have a (beta) product that performs this exact function. It's called [Flomio Kiosk](http://flomio.com/nfc-kiosk/). The way it works is with NFC wristbands and Android NFC terminals like the [Galaxy S4 Zoom](http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxycamera/s4zoom/specifications.html). The system lets guests associate wristbands/cards to their Facebook or Email accounts. The [NFC Kiosk application](http://flomio.com/shop/nfc-apps/nfc-kiosk/) has a photographer mode that allows pictures taken to be tagged and uploaded with the scanned wristband's profile.

The architecture of the stack is straightforward. The UUID of the wristbands are associated with the Facebook token of the associated guest. This needs to be stored in a cloud server so that you can effectively OAuth2.0 to Facebook and post on behalf of the guest. This setup also allows us to remain liability free of ill formed posts. Each developer that uses our system needs to create their own Facebook app and get it approved. If spam or content that violates Facebook T&C is posted then only that Facebook app will be shutdown rather than the whole Flomio Kiosk solution.

In order for us to grab the Facebook token for each guest, the guest must go to the events' landing page (we use eventname.flomio.com), enter their wristband code (5 digit number) and sign in with their Facebook credentials. The guest can then select what permissions to give the event application, such as post to "Only Me" and allow access to their "News Feed". Once this registration process is complete the wristband is considered activated and the OAuth token for accessing the guests Facebook profile is stored in the Flomio database alongside the wristband UUID.

When a wristband is scanned at an access point, the UUID is sent up to Flomio via websockets for ultra-fast responsiveness that reveals the guest name and profile picture. This way event organizers can provide a more personalized experience to guests. In photographer mode, the images are taken and then wristbands are scanned. Images are posted through Flomio where event logos are overlaid on the pictures for added brand recognition. Included are predefined post messages as well that event organizers can curate before hand. Here's a simple diagram of how things come together.

[image]

For high end cameras like the Nikon D300 we use the [Transcend Wifi SDcards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A659ILQ) as they're more hacker friendly. These run Linux so we execute some scripts to tag the photos as soon as they're taken but upload them later through a background process. Our Kiosk solution is undergoing maintenance right now to add support for our FloJack and FloBLE product lines. Once complete any smartphone will be able to act as a scan terminal in a multitude of deployment scenarios. Sign up for [our blog](http://flomio.com/blog/) to stay tuned with our latest releases.